# laravel not picking file through asset()

Tags: laravel

In my laravel project i am trying to get js file though asset('js/app.js') which is inside public folder. it is working fine on localhost but on server it is not picking file. It is working on another server. I think there is any issue with htaccess file.

I try to use url() and URL::asset() but not working. I checked source of page link is perfect but still fail to pick file

I want to access that js file.

Comment: if you try to load the app.js file in the browser with the link you found in the html source what is the error?

Comment: this is error NotFoundHttpException it is route error

Comment: please check file permissions and ownership

Comment: of which folder? all?

Comment: of the app.js file and the js folder

Comment: i gave it 777 permission ,but still not working ... what to check about ownership?

Comment: where is your htacces file, under public drectory or under laravel root directory?

Comment: under root directory

Comment: please try asset('public/js/app.js'), and find a way to serve your site from public not from root, it's extremely unsecure. Did I say extremely?

Comment: done. it works for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question has been answered in the comments, and was solved with this code:

```
asset('public/js/app.js')
```